# Laravel orders database architecture advice

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, architecture, entity-relationship

I've been setting a Orders system for a Laravel 5.8 app but I presume I've overcomplicated (or not) the DB architecture for the Orders system.

I created the following tables: `order`, `order_items`, `products`, `services`, `prices` and of course using the `users` table as 'client'.

My doubt now is between having the `products` and `services` as separate tables or use just on new as `items` which would state if the item is a 'product' or 'service'.

This because when establishing the Models relationships for the `Order::class` and `OrderItem::class` models I seem to have gotten into a 'knot'.

My tables are the following:

**orders**

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| guid        | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(10) unsigned    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| firm_id     | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| currency_id | int(10) unsigned    | YES  | MUL | 1       |                |
| total       | double(8,2)         | NO   |     | 0.00    |                |
| status      | varchar(191)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**order_items**

```
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id    | int(10) unsigned    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| service_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| order_id      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| quantity      | double(8,2)         | NO   |     | 1.00    |                |
| quantity_type | varchar(191)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| notes         | varchar(191)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at    | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**products**

```
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| guid         | varchar(191)        | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| name         | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name_slug    | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| details      | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| has_shipment | tinyint(1)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at   | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**services**

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| guid        | varchar(191)        | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name_slug   | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | text                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**prices**

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id  | int(11)             | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| service_id  | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| currency_id | int(10) unsigned    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value       | double(8,2)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**users** (simplified)

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| guid        | varchar(191)        | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name_slug   | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(191)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ...         | ...                 | ...  | ... | ...     | ...            |
| created_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at  | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My goal is to have the **Order** with one or more **Products** and/or **Services**, with their respective prices for a user.

Example:
`$order = Order::where('id', 1)->with('users', 'items', 'prices')->get();`

But I can fetch the 'Order', with the 'User', 'Items' but not the 'Prices' for each item.

**What I've tried**

Different relationship approaches on the `Order::class` and `OrderItem::class` models (ex: `$this->belongsTo(Product::class)`) but seems to not getting it right.

As mentioned above I can get almost everything but not the prices.

**Question**: Should I merge the **Products** and **Services** into one table and have a column for the **type** (like *service*, *product*)?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that merge these tables not is the best way. In my opinion, this is a perfect usage for a polymorphic relationship. According to the Laravel's documentation:

> A polymorphic relationship allows the target model to belong to more than one type of model using a single association.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations. If you have some question, please, comment here. I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've thought about it but not very experienced in the Laravel polymorphic relationships. What I would guess from your answer, and please correct me if I'm wrong would be to change the `order_items ` table.  Delete the `product_id`, `service_id` and add the following columns: `ordereable_id`, and `orderable_type` to use the model `id` and the related model. For instance:  `ordereable_id = 1`, `orderable_type = Service` . I presume this would be the suggested approach right?

Comment: In this case I would have to add to the `OrderItem::class` (or `Order::class`?) the method
 `public function orderable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}`

Comment: The method should be added in `OrderItem::class`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make the suggested changes and hopefully this solves the issue that I got into it. :)